# How to display banner ad in eclipse using libgdx

Tags: android, admob

I am really new to programming. I have followed the tutorial in Libgdx and google,
but i cannot put a banner ad using admob in my application.
Can someone help me to teach what i should do to put admob banner ad in my application ?

Thank you,

Comment: Your question is too broad. What error are you getting.

Comment: @William Actually i am trying to include banner admob ad at the bottom of my main page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a View to contain both the adMob View and the Libgdx View, then setContentView() to this layout to which you must add both Views. Is [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx) the tutorial to which you refer? It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your android game-android project open the Activity and create a relative layout that is fullscreen and has no title bar as-

```
 RelativeLayout layout=new RelativeLayout(this);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Now below this change this line-

```
initialize(new Mygame(), cfg);
```

to

```
View gameView=initializeForView(new MyGame() , cfg);
```

This method *initializeForView(new MyGame() , cfg);* returns a view which is saved as a instance of view that will be added to the relative layout. Now create adview also to add to relative layout as-

```
Adview adView=new AdView(this);// create new adview instance
adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.BANNER);// set the adsize
adView.setAdUnitId("XXXXXXXXX");// your adunit id
//Create layout params for adview
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);//set position
//Add both gameview and adview to the relative layout-
layout.addView(gameView);
layout.addView(adView, adParams);
//Now just request ad by creating new instance of AdRequest
AdRequest request=new AdRequest.Builder().build();//.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) to add test device
adView.loadAd(request);
// At last setcontent view to the Relative Layout that has both gameView and adView.
setContentView(layout);
```

You need to override onPause , onResume  and onDestroy also to handle pause , resume  or destorying of ad.

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(adView!=null){
        adView.resume();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(adView!=null){
        adView.pause();
    }
}
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(adView!=null){
        adView.destroy();
    }
}
```

Upto here adView is added to your game, but if you want to handle on when to show adView.You may want to hide adView when game is running and show when game is over, which can be achieved  by creating handler.